# Is it possible to reference an environmental variable within a postgres sql command?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, say I wanted to import a CSV file from a path on the same machine the postgres server is running on.

There is an environmental variable `MyPath` set on the system to `'/path/to/my/csv/file/'`.

I could easily import this CSV file as follow:

```
COPY MyTable FROM
'/path/to/my/csv/file/myTable.csv'
DELIMITERS ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Is it possible to reference the MyPath variable from within this postgres sql command? Something along the following lines:

```
COPY MyTable FROM
get_environmental_variable('MyPath') || 'myTable.csv'
DELIMITERS ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this while starting

```
 psql --set 'var=foo' -c '\i thesqlscript'
```

And this in the query

```
update table set column = :var;
```

This is taken from [this question on the forum](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Passing-parameters-into-an-in-line-psql-invocation-td4448898.html)

If you are using an older version of postgres, this looks like the same question asked [in the postgres forum](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20041028122902.GB22647@cspcag.swan.ac.uk) (though this is many years ago). 
There is no direct way, but they have given a couple of workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

On Posix systems (Linux, MacOS)...

You may access environment variables for the **system user** matching the postgresql **role** you are using, usually the system **postgres** user (or whatever system user is running the postgres server).

Because `env` uses '=' as delimiter, splitting `k=v` means you have to prevent the presence of '=' in the string **values**.

You can do:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS env;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS env_tmp;
CREATE TEMP TABLE env_tmp(e text);
CREATE TEMP TABLE env(k text, v text);

COPY env_tmp ( e ) FROM PROGRAM 'env';

INSERT INTO env
SELECT (regexp_split_to_array(e,'={1,1}'))[1],
  (regexp_match(e, '={1,1}(.*)'))[1]
FROM env_tmp;

SELECT * FROM env;

            k             |         v                                                             
--------------------------+----------------------------
 LC_TIME                  | C
 DEPLOY_ENV               | local
 PG_VERSION               | 12.4-1.pgdg100+1
 LC_CTYPE                 | en_US.utf8
 LC_COLLATE               | en_US.utf8
 LANG                     | en_US.utf8
 LC_MESSAGES              | en_US.UTF-8
 PG_MAJOR                 | 12
 LC_NUMERIC               | C
 SERVICE_COMMAND          | postgres -c "config_file=postgresql.conf" -c "port=5432"

[...]
```

It should also possible to do something using the "CSV" version of COPY, I haven't tried that way.

Comment: great comment.

On windows I use `set` instead of `env`. In addition, I use `COPY env_tmp ( e ) FROM  PROGRAM 'set' with delimiter E'\001' escape E'\\' quote E'\003' CSV;` to avoid "eat up" of some important characters

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is not tied to using `psql` and it works cross-platform.

Answer (score 3):

If you install [PL/R](http://joeconway.com/plr/), you can use the plr_environ() function to get a list of environment variables and their values as `COPY MyTable from (SELECT VALUE FROM plr_environ() WHERE name = 'MyPath')` ; other stored procedure languages probably have similar ways -- in plpython, I'd imagine one could use os.environ['MyPath'], plperlu has access to the %ENV hash, and so on. If you need further help, please leave a comment and I'll be happy to look into this further for you.