# How can we read environment variable in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql function where I want to use get user defined environment variable. Is there any default function to get the environment variable directly ?

Comment: Potentially useful [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18673208).

Answer (score 0):

Since a function is running on the database server, you would get the **environment of the database server process** (I wonder if that is what you want). This should be restricted to superusers (or perhaps the `pg_execute_server_program` role).

There is no standard function for this, probably because it is mostly useless, but it should be easy to write a function in C, PL/PerlU or PL/PythonU to do that.

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64294517/4126114) gives access to the general server environment (not the database server process environment)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no SQL function available to do this.

But it should not be complicate to do using https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xfunc-c.html.